# Get row numbers from mysql_fetch_array result

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have pulled in the data from a mysql database using `select *` with the intention of using the data several times without doing repeated sql enquiries using `WHERE`.

Using this data I am extracting rows that contain a search element using

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query_result)){  <<<if match add to new array>>>  }
```

As there are thousands of rows this is taking a longer time than I want.

I am trying to use:

```
$row=mysql_fetch_array($query_result);
$a = array_search($word_to_check, $row);
echo $a;
```

This extracts the correct sql headings but not the row number. What I want to achieve is

if `$word` is found in mysql_fetch_array($query_result) the add the row where it was found into the new array for processing.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't you limit your query results with `WHERE`?

Comment: can the search word be found in multiple columns?

Comment: yes it can. `WHERE col1 = 'aaaa' OR col2 ='aaa';` There is also one good way for searching texts. You should read about full text index. And `match against` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use **mysql_* functions** they are depracated. Use **mysqli** or **pdo** instead.

It's not wise to search in array of mysql results in php while it can be done in mysql. Let's say you have table and you want to find all numbers in number column that are greater than 5

```
  SELECT FROM table_name WHERE number>5
```

to find text you can use simple clause

```
  SELECT FROM table_name WHERE name = 'username'
```

You can also create more complex conditions.

From MYSQL manual:

> WHERE clause, if given, indicates the condition or conditions that rows must satisfy to be selected. where_condition is an expression that evaluates to true for each row to be selected. The statement selects all rows if there is no WHERE clause

[Check this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies...what I am doing is checking a paragraph of text for words in the database so the routine could access the database 20 times with a 'where' query. If this is multiplied by 200 users is that not going to slow things down too much?

Comment: you can use `WHERE IN()` which is for sure faster than looking for values in PHP

Comment: I originally used sql accessing to get the appropriate rows but then convinced myself it was too much data accessing so went for the hold data and recycle option. So the database option is much faster even if there are hundreds of queries at the same time rather than each user getting data once and using it?

Comment: You can use **prepared statements** to improve perfomace and it's only about binding values than giving whole query to Db. So in this case it'll be faster.

Comment: I'm using the following with an array containing the table names. I could use this with a WHERE statement further in the script to access the database for specific information.$count=0;while($count<count($sql_word_query)){$select=$select."SELECT * FROM $sql_word_query[$count]";$count++;if($count<count($sql_word_query))$select=$select." UNION ALL ";}$result=mysql_query($select);$GLOBALS['query']=$select;

Comment: don't use $_GLOBALS, I don't like unions as well, as I suggested you read about prepared statements and change engine. It will be better for perfomace. Prepare statement and then in loop you can bind parameters and execute.

Comment: Thanks for all your advice everyone. I've set the script to use multiple sql requests and it is all working much faster than using one call and processing the array created. I'll look into prepared statements too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit the query to only once, fetch all the results into temporary array and do the search from it like below

```
<?php
$all_rows=array();
$match_rows=array();
$i=0;
$limit=100000;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query_result)){  
   $all_rows[]=$row;
   if($i % $limit == 0){  // this part only functions every 100,000 cycles.
      foreach($all_rows as $search_row){
        if(array_search($word_to_check, $search_row)
            $match_rows[]=$search_row;
        } 
      $all_rows=array();//reset temporary array
   }
   $i++;
}

//This solution assumes the required word can be found in mulitple columns
```

Comment: I was thinking along those lines...I did the first step and the data being processed - the temp array - has jumped from 1.5mb to 46.5 mb

Comment: @JohnMusgraveBolanos I think my updated answer addresses the memory issue.